# Minipage title structure problem

Tags: minipage

[image]

I can't have the title and dates on the same line in the right place just for this, rest of document is ok. I tried adjusting \textwidth in all possible ways and it is still not working

```
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
    \textbf{Tianjin Foreign Studies University}, French Language and Literature
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
  \textbf{Sep 11 - Jul 14} \\%[1.1cm]
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}


\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.5in]
\item \textbf{Obtained 93/100} in the graduation thesis
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! There is not enough room for a box of linewidth + one of 50% linewidth. Adjust the numbers to be <= 1 in total.

Comment: I'm curious why the minipage. Wouldn't it be simpler to have `\textbf{Tianjin Foreign Studies University} etc \hfill \textbf{Sep 11 - Jul 14}`?

Comment: you mean the 1 and 0.5? I did before all possible combinations and date still in line below

Comment: In whatever combination you choose, their sum should not exceed one, as pointed by samcarter.

Comment: @hec If you would add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of code fragments, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/yjQMUa4F98pMoxnU/www.sharelatex.com       \begin{minipage}{0.494\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
    \textbf{Tianjin Foreign Studies University}, French Language and Literature
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
  \textbf{Sep 11 - Jul 14} \\%[1.1cm]
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

Comment: \hfill trick seems to work!!

Comment: @samcarter, please be welcome to answer it. Though my comment seems to have been useful, the answer to what has actually been asked is what you mentioned.

Comment: @gusbrs If you'd like, please add a `\hfill` answer. The minipage solution seems unnecessarily complicate...

Answer (score 3):

The combined with of the minipages in your example is 150% textwidth, which will not fit on a single line. The result is that you second minipage is moved to the next line.

As soon as the combined with is <= textwidth, they will be placed next to each other. As bonus you can specify that the content of the minipage shall be top aligned using the option `[t]`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
\textbf{Tianjin Foreign Studies University}, 

French Language and Literature
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\hfill\textbf{Sep 11 - Jul 14}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Overfull \hbox (17.22221pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--16`. (Paragraph indent and space between minipages.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. very true (I've included your insight in my answer). But the original document seems to have no paragraph indent, and we had no MWE to start with.

Comment: samcarter, I pillaged your MWE, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @gusbrs In return I browned a missing % - guess we are square :)

Comment: Thats to TorbjørnT.'s credit though!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for you comment! This is of course correct.

Answer (score 3):

Just complementing [samcarter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401450/105447) with an alternative for the case mentioned in the comments.

The minipage seems to have been set for a case where the title is long enough not to fit the line along with the right side date.
But in cases such as this one, in which that doesn't happen, a simpler alternative with `\hfill` is available with the same effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Tianjin Foreign Studies University} \hfill \textbf{Sep 11 - Jul 14}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The minipage might be needed though, if the title is too long. Provided you take care of indent (probably already done in your document) and the space between the two minipages, you can set them to sum exactly one textwidth, which simplifies things.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent % <-- if your document doesn't set this globally you should add it, otherwise you will have less than 1 textwidth available
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
\textbf{Tianjin Foreign Studies University}, French Language and Literature
\end{minipage}% <-- notice the percent sign, so there is no space between minipages, otherwise you will have less than 1 textwidth available
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\hfill\textbf{Sep 11 - Jul 14} % here `\hfill` substitutes your `flushright` environment
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]